# Rust index from end

Tags: rust, slice

How do I index from the end in Rust?

`assert "hello world"[-5:] == "world"` --> `assert_eq!(&"hello world".to_owned()[-5..], "world".to_owned())`

Any good online resource for python-to-rust slicing. Lots on how the borrowing works but very little on "advanced" slicing (ie. `[::-1]`)

Comment: Note that you also have [`.ends_with()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.ends_with) on string slices, which avoids counting the letters (the same goes for Python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the index from end case you had the solution in the first version of the question, calculate the start index and use it instead.
Of course you can do that programatically as well:

```rust
let h = "hellow world";
assert_eq!(h[h.len()-5..].to_owned(), "world".to_owned());
```

For the reverse case you got 2 options:

- use `rev()` on a corresponding iterator:

```rust
for c in "hello world".chars().rev() {
    print!("{c}");
}
println!();
```

prints `dlrow olleh`

- reverse the slice in place (which is complicated for utf-8 so I show it with bytes instead):

```rust
let s: &mut [u8] = &mut [1, 2, 3];
s.reverse();
assert_eq!(s, &[3, 2, 1]);
```

[Playground link for all the examples in one go](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cd11157ae3ae397ede6f3e075e946e95)

Comment: Note that reversing the `.chars()` iterator is [just wrong](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0a246b78ace33fc66368f8c9e81320fb)

Comment: Yes and no, curiously enough your playground produces the correctly looking ["mörtsÅ"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gX3L.png) in it's output for me. But when I copy the chars I get what you're hinting at "m̈orts̊A" which in a way still is the reverse of the `char`s in "Åström".